# gutter-width in a CSS grid

Tags: css, grid, width

This may be a silly question, so my apologies in advance.

I'm designing a CSS grid for my website. The overall width of the grid is `1150px` divided into `12 columns`. But when it comes to the gutter width: It it best to use a small or big width? Or do you choose that depending on how you want your website to look/be styled?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gutter is a concept independent of CSS and it is related to a better legibility (easier to read).

There is no predefined rule about the width. Just set the whitespace between columns to some value that you want.

This value depends about what you looking for in your website (legibility, structure, design, information architecture ).